# push is not a function

Tags: javascript, vue.js

первый раз работаю с js и vue для учебного проекта.

Возникла ошибка

Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: this.testcases.push is not a function.

Поискал похожие вопросы, в них говорилось о том, что не совпадают возвращаемые значения (Массив и объект). Но,к сожалению, не понял ответа и не смог исправить ошибку.

```
var testcaseApi = Vue.resource('/testcase{/id}')

Vue.component('testcase-form',{
props:['testcases'],
data:function() {
    return {
        author: '',
        update_date: "2021-01-01",
        creation_date: "2021-01-01",
        case_name: '',
        step: '',
        input_data: '',
        result: '',
        chain_id: 0,
        testplan_id: 0,
        element_id: 0
    }
    },
template:
'<div>'+
    '<input type="text" placeholder="Автор" v-model="author"/>'+
    '<input type="datetime-local" placeholder="Дата изменения" v-model="update_date"/>'+
    '<input type="datetime-local" placeholder="Дата создания" v-model="creation_date"/>'+
    '<input type="text" placeholder="Название" v-model="case_name"/>'+
    '<input type="text" placeholder="Шаг тестирования" v-model="step"/>'+
    '<input type="text" placeholder="Входные данные" v-model="input_data"/>'+
    '<input type="text" placeholder="Ожидаемый результат" v-model="result"/>'+
    '<input type="text" placeholder="chain_id" v-model="chain_id"/>'+
    '<input type="text" placeholder="testplan_id" v-model="testplan_id"/>'+
    '<input type="text" placeholder="element_id" v-model="element_id"/>'+
    '<input type="button" value="Save" @click="save"/>'+
    '</div>',
methods:{
    save:function (){
        var testcase = {
            author:this.author,
            update_date: this.update_date,
            creation_date: this.creation_date,
            case_name: this.case_name,
            step: this.step,
            input_data: this.input_data,
            result:this.result,
            chain_id: this.chain_id,
            testplan_id: this.testplan_id,
            element_id: this.element_id
        };

        testcaseApi.save({},testcase).then(result =>
        result.json().then(data=>{
            this.testcases.push(data);
            this.author = '';
            this.update_date = "2021-01-01";
            this.creation_date= "2021-01-01";
            this.case_name = '';
            this.step = '';
            this.input_data = '';
            this.result = '';
            this.chain_id = 0;
            this.testplan_id = 0;
            this.element_id = 0;
            })
        )
    }
}
```

})

```
Vue.component('testcases-list', {
    props:['testcases'],
    template:'<div>' +
        '<testcase-form testcases="testcases"/>'+
        '<testcase-row v-for="testcase in testcases" :key="testcase.id" :testcase="testcase" /></div>',
    created: function (){
        testcaseApi.get().then(result =>
        result.json().then(data=>
            data.forEach(testcase => this.testcases.push(testcase))
            )
        )
    }
});
```

Comment: как ты используешь этот компонент?

Comment: Извините, возможно не понял вопроса. Компонент используется для заполнения формы, код находится в единственном файле main.js, связанном с index.html. Это пример из учебного видео, вот github аналогичного кода из видео. https://github.com/drucoder/sarafan/blob/AddJPA/src/main/resources/static/js/main.js

Comment: добавь в вопрос непосредственно код как ты используешь этот компонент в разметке. То место где ты пишешь `<testcase-form ...`

Comment: Добавил в вопрос

Comment: а в каком именно месте `this.testcases.push` у тебя `not a function`? У тебя уже два компонента, которые принимают параметром массив, но неизвестно что именно ты им передаешь

Comment: так же обрати внимание, что в одном случае ты используешь `:testcase="testcase"` при передаче параметра, а в другом просто `testcases="testcases"`.  Посмотри что значит двоеточие при использовании в этом контексте

Comment: Ошибка в первом компоненте, testcase-form

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124479/discussion-between-grundy-and--).

Answer (score 1):

this.testcases - это объект, у объектов нет функции push. Для того, чтобы добавить элемент в объект используется конструкция либо `this.testcases.newOption = '123'`, либо `this.testcases['newOption'] = '123'`. Если нужно "сложить" два объекта используется Object.assign(). Для наглядности посмотрите в документации.

Comment: почему ты думаешь, что `this.testcases` это объект?

Comment: @Grundy, потому что в коде так написано. В функции save

Comment: смотри внимательнее код. в функции save объявляется testcase,  а не testcases

Comment: Да, я увидел. Тогда нужно просто смотреть через консоль, например, какой это тип.